# How can I test that a select has a given value in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I am very new to Cypress and I want to write a simple test that a select box (drop down) is set to a certain state when the page first loads. I don't want to set it to anything, which the instructions on the website clearly show. I just want to make sure when the page first loads the select box is set to what it should be. I am sure this is easy to do and I am looking over the documentation now. So far I have:

```javascript
cy.get('#sinkerTypeList')
```

I can't figure out how to make sure the selected item has the text "All Sinkers Types".

How can I test that a specific value is selected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress.IO: How do I get Text of selected option in select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222840/cypress-io-how-do-i-get-text-of-selected-option-in-select)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I got this to work:

```javascript
it('the selected option should be All Sinker Types', function () {
        cy.get('#sinkerTypeList')
            .find(':selected').contains('All Sinker Types')
})
```