# Cypress: How do I get the text of the selected option in a select drop-down list?

Tags: cypress

I want to be able to get the text of the selected option and not the value. I would use the value but Angular is changing it and putting the value in a `ng-reflect-ng-value` attribute.

```html
<option _ngcontent-c1="" value="5: 1" ng-reflect-ng-value="1">Miscellaenous</option>
```

This will work, but I want to check that it equals "Miscellaenous"

```javascript
cy.get('#id-9999').find('.categoryList').should('have.value','Miscellaenous');
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This worked for me:

```javascript
cy.get('#id-9999').find('.categoryList').find(':selected').contains('Miscellaenous')
```

Comment: I will see if I can delete this question, because I already answered it myself in another post. DUH!

Comment: Haha. Flag it as a duplicate linking to your previous question since it may not allow you to delete as at least one answer is present.

Comment: I flagged the original as a duplicate, since this one has gotten far more traction: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48666908/1108305

Comment: I removed the bit about the duplicate question from this answer.  It was OK context originally, but as this question ages it's not particularly relevant to the actual answer.  Removed text: "Well I had a brain fart and I had actually asked this question before and forgot how to do it."

Answer (score 25):

This is how it should be done:

```js
cy.get('#id-9999').find('option:selected').should('have.text', 'Miscellaenous');
```

Among other things, it checks for the exact match and not for a substring (like in your solution).

Comment: I think you are on to something. I like this way better!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

We've found that chaining find() off get() sometimes breaks our tests, so we use this other way:

```
cy.get("#my-select-element option:selected")
   .should("have.value", 3);
```

as opposed to:

```
cy.get("#my-select-element")
   .find("selected")
   .should("have.value", 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Cypress I found that :selected did not work, however :checked did work. So to modify one of the other answers here, this works (at least for me):

```
cy.get("#my-select-element option:checked")
   .should("have.value", 3);
```