# Cypress select to match value on multiSelect listbox

Tags: angular, listbox, cypress, multi-select

When I run this:

```js
cy.get('select#account').select('phChecking')
  .should('have.value', 'phChecking')
```

I am trying to verify that the option is there and select it in a multiSelect listBox.

Currently, this fails as the return is in array format.

> Error:    AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms:
> expected '<select#account.form-control.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-dirty>' to have value 'phChecking', but the value was [ '0: 'phChecking'' ]

A few attempts to match that:

```js
cy.get('select#account').select('phChecking')
  .should('have.value', [ '0: \'phChecking\'' ])
```

resulted in:

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<select#account.form-control.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-dirty>' to have value [ '0: 'phChecking'' ], but the value was [ '0: 'phChecking'' ]

Yes, they do look the same to me.  Anyway, I'm trying to select the item and assert that it is there at the same time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress: How do I get the text of the selected option in a select drop-down list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222840/cypress-how-do-i-get-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-a-select-drop-down-list)

Comment: Thanks for showing that.  Not sure I'd have gotten there from that as I was unclear on the link.  The answers here definitely nailed it.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the text instead of the value is one way to test the multi-select.

But the value you are getting `['0': 'phChecking']` is an array, because it is a ***multi-select***, and you are able to have more than one value selected.

If you selected two items you would see something like

```js
[ '0': 'phChecking', '1': 'phSavings' ]
```

When the result of a query is an array, you can't use a simple `eq` to compare them because they are different arrays. `eq` only compares the references (the array objects), not the contents of the arrays.

Use `deep.eq` instead:

```js
cy.get('select#account')
  .select('phChecking')

cy.get('select#account')
  .invoke('val')
  .should('deep.eq', ['0': 'phChecking'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this question [How do I get the text of the selected option in a select drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222840/cypress-how-do-i-get-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-a-select-drop-down-list).

The exact approach often depends on the framework, but since that question is also about Angular, it is worth a try.

```js
cy.get('select#account')
  .select('phChecking')

cy.get('select#account')
  .find('options')
  .find(':selected')
  .should('contain', 'phChecking')
```

I separated the action and the assertion in case there is any asynchronous event handler on the element.

In general you must not assert in the same chain as an action, see [select command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select)

> It is **unsafe** to chain further commands that rely on the subject after `.select()`