# How to assert which value is selected in drop-down

Tags: cypress

All the docs seem to be explaining how to select a value in a drop-down, but I need to assert that a specific value is selected, without making any changes.
I'm new to Cypress, so haven't been able to figure it out yet.

I tried `cy.get('.selector').contains('expected string');` but the test fails with this error message --

```
expected <.selector> to have value 1st of the month after 60 days, but the value was ''
```

and [Cypress.IO Select Drop Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666908/cypress-io-select-drop-down) didn't help either.

Fwiw, the selector is Vuetify's `v-select`

Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure that this element has any text?

Comment: Definitely. I can see it on the page

Comment: But is the text node child of this `.selector` element?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

```
<select><option value="Alice">Bob</option> ... </select>
```

In a cypress test you can write:

```
cy.get('select').select('Bob').should('have.value', 'Alice')
```

Comment: But I'm using `v-select` which is populated with `v-model`, so the syntax isn't the same

Answer (score 0):

Assume:

Bob ...

In a cypress test you can write:

cy.get('select').select("Alice");

cy.get('select').find('option[value="Alice"]').should("be.selected");